# finding projects on github / bitbucket

Tags: github, bitbucket

Is there a simple way to find projects that use a certain library (say django / rails) on github or bitbucket? Just typing "rails" in the search returns projects with "rails" being part of the name, but those are not necessarily rails applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google `site:github.com routes.rb` and you'll get page upon page of Rails app repos.

I think that's a good starting point. There are many ways to further refine the search.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. This would be basically impossible.

Github could let you search by language, because there are a finite number of programming languages and it's (generally) pretty easy to tell which language(s) a project is written in.

There is no simple way to tell which *libraries* a given project uses. Github would have to write detectors for *thousands* of different libraries, and the detector would have to work *against* thousands of different ways of including those libraries.